# x range is invalid. Maybe timefmt wrong

Tags: gnuplot

I have the following script

```gnuplot
set datafile separator ","
set grid

set autoscale

set timefmt "%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
set xdata time

plot 'test.txt' using 1:2 with lines
```

Data

```
2017-09-01 13:15:29,615,668
2017-09-01 13:15:29,615,666 
2017-09-01 13:15:29,614,666
2017-09-01 13:15:29,615,666
2017-09-01 13:15:29,615,665
2017-09-01 13:19:52,614,660
2017-09-01 13:19:52,615,661
```

I want to plot this data which was generated by postgresql. Since hours i cant figure out why i get

```
gnuplot> plot 'test.txt' using 1:2 with lines
                                             ^
         "strom-plot.txt", line 9: x range is invalid
```

Any hint would be appreciated.

EDIT: I am on gnuplot 5.0 patchlevel 5 debian stretch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is an error in your `timefmt` argument. You should be using `%Y` instead of `%y`. From `help timefmt`:

> ```
> Format       Explanation
> %y           year, 0--99
> %Y           year, 4-digit
> ```

This works here:

```gnuplot
set datafile separator ","
set grid

set autoscale

set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
set xdata time

plot 'test.txt' using 1:2 with lines
```

Result:

[image: Plot of first and second columns]

Comment: Thanks, I had the same error message, and adding `set datafile separator ","` fixed it.